# Camera access with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, camera, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mobile, xamarin.forms.labs

Is anyone able to give a short, self-contained example on how to access the camera with Xamarin.Forms 1.3.x? Simply calling the native camera application and retrieving the resulting picture would be great. Displaying a live view on the Xamarin.Forms page would be awesome!

I already tried to use Xamarin.Mobile and Xamarin.Forms.Labs, but I couldn't get any solution to work on both platforms (focussing on Android and iOS for now). Most code snippets found on the web (including stackoverflow) are incomplete, e.g. not showing the implementation of an IMediaPicker object or where to anchor the method for taking pictures.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I finally created a minimum solution for iOS and Android.

### The shared project

First, let's look into the shared code. For an easy interaction between the shared `App` class and the platform-specific code we store a static `Instance` within the `public static App`:

```cs
public static App Instance;
```

Furthermore, we will display an `Image`, which will be filled with content later. So we create a member:

```
readonly Image image = new Image();
```

Within the `App` constructor we store the `Instance` and create the page content, which is a simple `button` and the aforementioned `image`:

```
public App()
{
   Instance = this;

   var button = new Button {
       Text = "Snap!",
       Command = new Command(o => ShouldTakePicture()),
   };

   MainPage = new ContentPage {
       Content = new StackLayout {
       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
           Children = {
                    button,
                    image,
           },
       },
   };
}
```

The button's click handler calls the event `ShouldTakePicture`.
It is a public member and the platform-specific code parts will assign to it later on.

```
public event Action ShouldTakePicture = () => {};
```

Finally, we offer a public method for displaying the captured image:

```
public void ShowImage(string filepath)
{
    image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(filepath);
}
```

### The Android project

On Android we modify the `MainActivity`.
First, we define a path for the captured image file:

```
static readonly File file = new File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures), "tmp.jpg");
```

At the end of `OnCreate` we can use the static `Instance` of the created `App` and assign an anonymous event handler, which will start a new `Intent` for capturing an image:

```
App.Instance.ShouldTakePicture += () => {
   var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
   intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(file));
   StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
};
```

Last but not least, our activity has to react on the resulting image. It will simply push its file path to the shared `ShowImage` method.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
   base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   App.Instance.ShowImage(file.Path);
}
```

That's about it!
Just don't forget to set the "Camera" and the "WriteExternalStorage" permission within "AndroidManifest.xml"!

### The iOS project

For the iOS implementation we create a custom renderer.
Therefore, we add a new file "CustomContentPageRenderer" and add the corresponding assembly attribute right after the using statements:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(CustomContentPageRenderer))]
```

The `CustomContentPageRenderer` inherits from `PageRenderer`:

```
public class CustomContentPageRenderer: PageRenderer
{
    ...
}
```

We override the `ViewDidAppear` method and add the following parts.

Create a new image picker controller referring to the camera:

```
var imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController { SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera };
```

Present the image picker controller, as soon as the `ShouldTakePicture` event is raised:

```
App.Instance.ShouldTakePicture += () => PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, null);
```

After taking the picture, save it to the `MyDocuments` folder and call the shared `ShowImage` method:

```
imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += (sender, e) => {
            var filepath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "tmp.png");
var image = (UIImage)e.Info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"));
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                image.AsPNG().Save(filepath, false);
                App.Instance.ShowImage(filepath);
            });
            DismissViewController(true, null);
        };
```

And finally, we need to handle a cancellation of the image taking process:

```
imagePicker.Canceled += (sender, e) => DismissViewController(true, null);
```

Comment: Do you have a github resource of this? I cannot get it to work locally and im very curious as to what im doing differently/wrong.

Comment: Hey I need the exact same thing, but I could not get it working only with the code above, do you have this code on github or somewhere else?

Comment: @NorborIllig You might want to look into [this slightly newer and simplified version](http://xforms-kickstarter.com/#camera).

Comment: I got the 'slightly newer and simplified' version running. Awesome! Thanks so much @Falko. But struggling to work out how to adapt it to display the live view on a page other than the home page (on iOS, for starters). Would anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: For a page other than the home page, this works (iOS):
UIImagePickerController imagePicker =       new UIImagePickerController { SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera };      UIWindow window= UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;     UIViewController vc = window.RootViewController;     while ( vc.PresentedViewController != null )      vc = vc.PresentedViewController;      vc.PresentViewController ( imagePicker, true, null );

Comment: @Falko Can I capture more than 1 photo at a time and pass it to file?variable if yes How?

Comment: @NorborIllig see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506008/how-to-capture-multiple-photos-with-camera-xamarin-forms-android

Answer (score 5):

Try out James Montemagno's [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin).

You can install the plugin using [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) by simply typing and running `Install-Package Xam.Plugin.Media -Version 2.6.2` or else go to [Manage NuGet Packages...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui) and type `Xam.Plugin.Media` and install the plugin. (The plugins has to be installed in all your projects - including the client projects)

A *readme.txt* will be prompted and follow the instructions there. After that, [add the following codes](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/samples/MediaSample/MediaSample/MediaPage.xaml.cs) (as required) to your shared project. The instructions to be followed in the above *readme.txt* file are as follows.

#### For Android Project

In  your BaseActivity or MainActivity (for Xamarin.Forms) add this code:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

You must also add a few additional configuration files to adhere to the new strict mode:

1. Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml inside the <**application**> tags:

   ```
   <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
             android:authorities="YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME.fileprovider" 
             android:exported="false" 
             android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                  android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
   </provider>
   ```

   YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME must be set to your app package name!
2. Add a new folder called xml into your Resources folder and add a new XML file called `file_paths.xml`

   Add the following code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/files/Pictures" />
       <external-path name="my_movies" path="Android/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/files/Movies" />
   </paths>
   ```

   YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME must be set to your app package name!

#### For iOS Project

Your app is required to have keys in your Info.plist for `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in order to access the device's camera and photo/video library. If you are using the Video capabilities of the library then you must also add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`.  The string that you provide for each of these keys will be displayed to the user when they are prompted to provide permission to access these device features.

Such as:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to microphone.</string>
```

#### For Shared Project

To simply open camera, save photo and display an alert with the file path, enter the following to the shared project.

```
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
{
    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
    return;
}

var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
    Directory = "Sample",
    Name = "test.jpg"
});

if (file == null)
    return;

await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");
```

Comment: Hi, may I know how to activate the flash light automatically while the camera was activate?

Comment: Hello, for media plugin, there have default camera which is 
DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front

If i want make the flash light was always on, so any default function can be set like the default camera?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it on Xamarin Forms cross Xamarin iOS.

This is a good base to start but it requires a Page to rendered first in which you could just specify the UIApplication for it to provide the UIView for Camera / Photo Picker controllers.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28299259/1941942

#### Portable Project

```
public interface ICameraProvider
{
    Task<CameraResult> TakePhotoAsync();
    Task<CameraResult> PickPhotoAsync();
}

private Command AttachImage 
{
    var camera = await DependencyService.Get<ICameraProvider>().TakePhotoAsync();
}
```

#### iOS Project

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(CameraProvider))]

public class CameraProvider : ICameraProvider
{
    private UIImagePickerController _imagePicker;
    private CameraResult _result;
    private static TaskCompletionSource<CameraResult> _tcs;

    public async Task<CameraResult> TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CameraResult>();

        _imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController { SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera };

        _imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _result = new CameraResult();
            var filepath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "tmp.png");
            var image = (UIImage)e.Info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"));

            _result.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(image.AsPNG().ToArray())); 
            _result.ImageBytes = image.AsPNG().ToArray();
            _result.FilePath = filepath;

            _tcs.TrySetResult(_result);
            _imagePicker.DismissViewController(true, null);
        };

        _imagePicker.Canceled += (sender, e) =>
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
        };

        await UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewControllerAsync(_imagePicker, true);

        return await _tcs.Task; 
    }

    public async Task<CameraResult> PickPhotoAsync()
    {
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CameraResult>();

        _imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController
        {
            SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary,
            MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
        };

        _imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += (sender, e) =>
        {

            if (e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaType].ToString() == "public.image")
            {
                var filepath = (e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl")] as NSUrl);
                var image = (UIImage)e.Info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"));
                //var image = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;

                _result.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(image.AsPNG().ToArray()));
                _result.ImageBytes = image.AsPNG().ToArray();
                _result.FilePath = filepath?.Path;
            }

            _tcs.TrySetResult(_result);
            _imagePicker.DismissViewController(true, null);
        };

        _imagePicker.Canceled += (sender, e) =>
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
        };

        await UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewControllerAsync(_imagePicker, true);

        return await _tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I needed to get async camera-capture running in my app:

### In iOS:

```
public async Task<string> TakePicture()
{
    if (await AuthorizeCameraUse())
    {
        var imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController { SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera };

        TaskCompletionSource<string> FinishedCamera = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        // When user has taken picture
        imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += (sender, e) => {
            // Save the file
            var filepath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "tmp.png");
            var image = (UIImage)e.Info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"));
            image.AsPNG().Save(filepath, false);

            // Close the window
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);

            // Stop awaiting
            FinishedCamera.SetResult(filepath);
        };

        // When user clicks cancel 
        imagePicker.Canceled += (sender, e) =>
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
            FinishedCamera.TrySetCanceled();
        };

        // Show the camera-capture window
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, null);

        // Now await for the task to complete or be cancelled
        try
        {
            // Return the path we've saved the image in
            return await FinishedCamera.Task;
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            // handle if the user clicks cancel
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And if you need the authorization routine, make sure you also fill out the camera use in `info.plist` too, and here's the function to get authorization:

```
public static async Task<bool> AuthorizeCameraUse()
{
    var authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.GetAuthorizationStatus(AVMediaType.Video);

    if (authorizationStatus != AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
    {
        return await AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaTypeAsync(AVMediaType.Video);
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

---

### In Android:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _tcs_NativeCamera;

public async Task<string> TakePicture()
{
    _tcs_NativeCamera = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    // Launch the camera activity
    var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(cameraCaptureFilePath));

    NextCaptureType = stype;

    StartActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_NATIVE_CAMERA_CAPTURE_ASYNC);

    // Wait here for the activity return (through OnActivityResult)
    var Result = await _tcs_NativeCamera.Task;

    // Return the camera capture file path
    return Result != Result.Canceled ? cameraCaptureFilePath : null;
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case SCAN_NATIVE_CAMERA_CAPTURE_ASYNC:
            _tcs_NativeCamera.SetResult(resultCode);
            break;
    }
}
```