# How to Capture multiple photos with Camera xamarin Forms android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing Xamrin form application. Inside it, I am trying to capture multiple photos using a camera with the same intent. without using any `nuget` package?

for this, I am following this link [Camera](http://xforms-kickstarter.com/#camera)

```
MainActivity.cs

static readonly File file = new File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DirectoryPictures), "tmp.jpg");
```

> At the end of OnCreate

```
(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current as App).ShouldTakePicture += () => {
    var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(file));
    StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
};
```

here I am getting only 1 photo on clicking camera button but I want to capture more photo and I want its file path

> in OnActivityResult

```
(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current as App).ShowImage(file.Path);
```

but maybe it has few limitations such as we can not capture multiple photos at a time? Is anyone is having an idea how to capture multiple photos and bind it to listview?

Comment: Post your code here, even if you follow a tutorial you could've made some mistakes which we are unable to see due to the fact you haven't posted your code. Without that, this question would be primarily opinion based so we would have to close it.

Comment: @m.rogalski added the complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes after so much struggle I am able to do this. It may be helpful for someone who is working on such things in xamarin forms.

This is my code

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
       // public static App Instance;

        public App ()
        {
            MainPage = new CameraGallery.MainPage();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

> // please install FlowListView and ffimageloading nuget pckg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CameraGallery"
             x:Class="CameraGallery.MainPage"
             xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"> 

            <StackLayout x:Name="CameraLayout">
                <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" x:Name="listItemsCam" 
                        SeparatorVisibility="None"
                        HasUnevenRows="false" RowHeight="100" >
                    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage  DownsampleToViewSize="true" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HeightRequest="100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Source="{Binding .}"  Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView>
                <!--<Image x:Name="image" IsVisible="False"></Image>-->
            </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            ObservableCollection<string> camImageCollection;
            public static MainPage Instance;

            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Instance = this;

                var btn = new Button
                {
                    Text = "Snap!",
                    Command = new Command(o => ShouldTakePicture()),
                };
                CameraLayout.Children.Add(btn);  

                camImageCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            }
            public event Action ShouldTakePicture = () => { };

            public void ShowImage(string[] filepath)
            {
               foreach(var item in filepath)
                 camImageCollection.Add(item);
                 listItemsCam.FlowItemsSource = camImageCollection;
            }
        }
```

now go to your android project inside it MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "CameraGallery", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static int OPENCAMERACODE = 102;
        //inside OnCreate after LoadApplication(new App()); add these lines
         protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            FlowListView.Init();
            CachedImageRenderer.Init(false);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            MainPage.Instance.ShouldTakePicture += () =>
            {
                ICursor cursor = loadCursor();
                image_count_before = cursor.Count;
                cursor.Close();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.IntentActionStillImageCamera);
                IList<ResolveInfo> activities = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
                if(activities.Count >0)
                    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Camera Capture"), OPENCAMERACODE);
            };
        }
        public ICursor loadCursor()
        {
            string[] columns = new string[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Id };
            string orderBy = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DateAdded;
            return ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, columns, null, null, orderBy);
        }
        private void exitingCamera()
        {
            ICursor cursor = loadCursor();
            string[] paths = getImagePaths(cursor, image_count_before);
            MainPage.Instance.ShowImage(paths);// this parameter pass to MainPage.xaml.cs
            cursor.Close();
        }
        public string[] getImagePaths(ICursor cursor, int startPosition)
        {
            int size = cursor.Count - startPosition;
            if (size <= 0) return null;
            string[] paths = new string[size];

            int dataColumnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
            for (int i = startPosition; i < cursor.Count; i++)
            {
                cursor.MoveToPosition(i);

                paths[i - startPosition] = cursor.GetString(dataColumnIndex);
            }
            return paths;
        }
        //inside OnActivityResult method do this
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case 102:
                        exitingCamera();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this help someone. enjoy coding...